# React native NoClassDefFoundError: versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.admob.RNPublisherBannerViewManager

Tags: react-native

I have a problem related with react native app android build.

Application was created using expo and exported in order to implement firebase notifications.

After running the app crashes and give this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.admob.RNPublisherBannerViewManager
                                                                  at versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.admob.RNAdMobPackage.createViewManagers(RNAdMobPackage.java:33)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createAllViewManagers(ReactInstanceManager.java:746)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.createUIManager(CoreModulesPackage.java:190)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.access$200(CoreModulesPackage.java:69)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage$8.get(CoreModulesPackage.java:149)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage$8.get(CoreModulesPackage.java:146)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.LazyReactPackage.createNativeModules(LazyReactPackage.java:81)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:106)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1093)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1064)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:996)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600(ReactInstanceManager.java:107)
                                                                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$4.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:832)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What could be the problem? How can i Solve it?

This is currently my gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.sensmedia.diez"
      minSdkVersion 19
      targetSdkVersion 27
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      multiDexEnabled true
      ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
      }
      manifestPlaceholders = [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.sensmedia.diez'
      ]
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
    dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }
    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INFTICE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INFTICE'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      exclude 'META-INFtice.txt'
      exclude 'META-INFcense.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
      exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties'
    }
  }

  task exponentPrebuildStep(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '../../'

    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
      commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '.\\.expo-source\\android\\detach-scripts\\prepare-detached-build.bat'
    } else {
      commandLine './.expo-source/android/detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'
    }
  }
  preBuild.dependsOn exponentPrebuildStep

  repositories{
    flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {

    compile(project(':react-native-fcm')) {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
      exclude group: "com.google.firebase"
    }
    compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1') {
      force = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1') {
      force = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'

    compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:22.0.0@aar') {
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk'
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'audience-network-sdk'
      exclude group: 'io.nlopez.smartlocation', module: 'library'
      exclude module: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
      transitive = true;
    }

    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+') {
      exclude module: 'bolts-android'
      exclude module: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+') {
      exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
      exclude module: 'bolts-android'
      exclude module: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
      transitive = false
      exclude module: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }



  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```